# How to stop RDP from auto-appending organization email?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm connecting to a VM with username xxx. However, when RDP saves my credentials, it saves my username as xxx@xxx.com, which is not the correct login. I tried opening the credential config file but couldn't find the username. How can I set the username as xxx and prevent RDP from appending '@xxx.com' to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving `.\xxx` or `VMNAME\xxx` as the user name. (Replace VMNAME with the VM's actual hostname.)

All Windows usernames have a 'domain', either in the form of `DOMAIN\name` for old NT4 domain syntax or in the form of `name@domain` for Active Directory UPNs (*not* email addresses!). This applies even to standalone machines that aren't part of any domain – local accounts use the system's own hostname as the NT4 domain name.

In your case, it sounds like you're connecting *from* an AD-joined machine, so it's automatically adding its own AD domain and saving the username in UPN format. But if you manually provide the domain name, it should be saved as-is.

But if the VM *is* joined to an AD domain, then `name@domain` is *correct* – that should be the account's UPN, allowing the RDP connection to use Kerberos authentication (instead of the older NTLM).

Comment: thanks, `./` did it for me